# Bugs after the transition is complete jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, web-applications

When the transition is completed in jQuery Mobile, some elements are not well positioned  immediately.

There is a time between the transition is complete, and jQuery Mobile apply all styles and script (custom CSSs + JavaScript) in the new Page.

Is there any way in which the new page is displayed once all styles and scripts have been applied?

Maybe I could show the wait animation (provides by jQuery Mobile). But what would be the event that I must listen to know that everything has been loaded on the new page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `pageshow` event, which is triggered when the content has been loaded and the transition to the target page has been completed.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", ":jqmData(role='page')", function() {
    // ...
});
```

See the documentation [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/).

Answer (score 0):

I would open the Developer Toolbar on Chrome and investigate the Net tab for any delays in loading the assets required by the site. It is quite possible that a dependency related issue to do with a slow loading asset (CSS/images/Javascript) is causing this.

If this doesn't tell you enough information, I would run some Javascript profiling with Chrome to find out exactly which part of your Javascript is causing the delays. Please refer to the following guide:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/